# Difference between Product id and Package id

Tags: wix, wix3.8

I'm a newbie in using Wix. So, as the title says. What's the difference between Product id and Package id? Or are they one and the same? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To tell it short, Product Code identifies your application, while Package Code is the identification of the Windows Installer package itself.

You should read and understand the following two articles:

- [Product Codes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370860.aspx)
- [Package Codes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370568.aspx)

Here is the excerpt:

> The product and package codes are not interchangeable. No two
>   nonidentical .msi files should ever have the same package code.
>   Although it is common to ship an application that has the same package
>   code and product code, the two values can diverge as the application
>   is updated.

And some more:

> Although it is common to ship an application that has the same package
>   code and product code, the two values can diverge as the application
>   is updated. For example, including a new file with the application
>   would require updating the installation database to install the file.
>   If the changes are minor a developer may choose not to change the
>   product code, however, a different .msi file is needed to install the
>   new file and so the package code must be incremented. Conversely, a
>   single package can be used to install more than one product. For
>   example, the installation of a package without a language transform
>   could install the English version of the application and the
>   installation of the same package with a language transform could
>   install the French version. The transform is distinct from the .msi
>   file that determines the package code. The English and French versions
>   could have different product codes and the same package code because
>   they are both installed with the same .msi file.

Comment: And here I was searching for those documentations in the WiX site. Anyway, this made it clear. Thank you!